# tokudb insert speed with binlog on way slower than innodb?

Tags: mysql, innodb, percona, tokudb

TokuDB alone beat InnoDB in our benchmarks by about 25% but when I turn master-slave on InnoDB now beats TokuDB by about 20%

Any idea what's going on

here's the conf that's running on a r4.8xlarge aws machine

```
[mysql_safe]
malloc-lib=/usr/include/jemalloc


[mysqld]
user   = mysql
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port   = 3306
server-id = 1
log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db            = mt
sync_binlog=1
binlog_format=ROW
binlog_row_image=FULL
basedir    = /usr
datadir    = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir   = /tmp
lc-messages-dir  = /usr/share/mysql
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
#malloc-lib=/usr/include/jemalloc
key_buffer_size= 250G
read_buffer_size=2G
read_rnd_buffer_size=50M
join_buffer_size=25M
tmp_table_size = 5G
sort_buffer_size = 2G
query_cache_limit       = 10M
query_cache_size        = 100M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=64

tokudb_fanout = 128
tokudb_commit_sync = 0
tokudb_fsync_log_period = 1000
tokudb_directio = 1

# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.

innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 512M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 2
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 200G

log-error    = /var/log/mysql/error.log

# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_ALL_TABLES

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
```

Comment: Maybe your benchmarks are false? InnoDB isn't slower than TokuDB on fast drives since it can utilize CPU better. TokuDB performs better on slow drives.

Comment: the benchmark is pretty reliable, we went through it many times..

Comment: That means nothing sadly. You can't rely on something you did on your own if you won't disclose what you did, how you did it, on what kind of hardware, what the goal was, whether you hit CPU or I/O bottleneck and so on. InnoDB was never slow to begin with, TokuDB performed in linear fashion on slow drives. On fast drives, and on servers with sufficient memory for entire data set, InnoDB isn't slower than Toku.

Comment: `key_buffer_size= 250G` -- really??  How much RAM doyou have?  Are you using MyISAM?

Comment: 256G ram. using innodb